# How to check if my custom keyboard has been enabled in settings

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I am making a custom softkeyboard. Is there anyway to check if it has been enabled in settings?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turned out I just had to do this:

```
 InputMethodManager im = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
   String list = im.getEnabledInputMethodList().toString();
   if(list.contains(<MY KEYBOARD ID>)){
   //Do something
   }
```

Comment: Lmao, when you are too lazy to iterate the list of `InputMethod`s and just convert it to string :)

Answer (score 9):

Check below code :-

```
    String packageLocal = getPackageName();
    boolean isInputDeviceEnabled = false;
    InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    List<InputMethodInfo> list = inputMethodManager.getEnabledInputMethodList();

    // check if our keyboard is enabled as input method
    for (InputMethodInfo inputMethod : list) {
        String packageName = inputMethod.getPackageName();
        if (packageName.equals(packageLocal)) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Your Keyboard Enable",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I've prefered this answer because it is sillyly simple to just copy and past to project!

Comment: Thanks, bro!!! I logged into StackOverflow just to upvote your answer. Thanks a ton!!!

Comment: This gives you the list of all the enabled keyboards , how do we check for one keyboard specifically?

Answer (score 1):

Kotlin style:

```
    fun isCodeBoardEnabled(): Boolean {
        val imm = getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
        return imm.enabledInputMethodList.any { it.packageName == packageName }
    }
```